# How to parse the output returned from REST (/_api/)?

Tags: javascript, rest, ssom

When we use REST we get output as xml how do we parse this via **JSOM** and fetch the values?

Also, please provide some information on how to use this in **SSOM** instead of JSOM?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a REST call using JSOM?

Comment: I am asking 2 things: 1. when making REST call via JSOM and 2. when making REST calls via SSOM, how do we make use of the result returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default format for SharePoint REST endpoint is `application/atom+xml`. Instead of manipulating results returned in `Xml` format you could specify `JSON` format.

Use `accept header` to specify the format for response data from the server. To get the results in JSON format, include an `Accept header` set to `application/json;odata=verbose`.

### Examples

The code in the following example shows you how to request a JSON representation of all of the lists in a site by using

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d.results));
        },
        error: function (data) {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
});
```

C#

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists");
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: HI Vadim, I want to know the way in which we can access the result in c# and in javascript. You answer is related to c#. But suppose we use REST in javascript. Then how to parse result?

Comment: In JavaScript environment it returns JSON object. Since JSON is a subset of JavaScript, it can be used in the language with no muss or fuss. See the JavaScript example in the answer, for example, to retrieve the first list title:
var title = data.d.results[0].Title: